# Deserialize dynamic object in automapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I am fetching some data from third party API. In the response I am getting a dynamic location_info object

```json
{
  "country_code3": "SE",
  "country_name": "Sweden",
  "city_name": "Malmo",
  "latitude": 86.69,
  "longitude": 173.0551
}
```

Now I want to get the `country_name` and map it in property `Country` using AutoMapper. For that I want to deserialize above mentioned dynamic JSON into `LocationInfo` model:

```
public class LocationInfo
{
    public string Country_Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then AutoMapper will map `Country_Name` to `Country`. Here's what I have tried:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Country, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LocationInfo>(src.LocationInfo).Country_Name);
```

But it didn't work and I get the following exception:

> An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation.

Comment: A general rule of thumb is not to use AutoMapper when the majority (or all) of the properties can't be mapped by convention, since that misses the point of it being "auto"

Comment: It looks like your API is returning a JSON response. I highly suggest using [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/) and use `[JsonProperty("country_name")]` on your model's `Country`.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Comment: As Jimmy Bogard, Automapper's author explains `if your config isn't 95% "Auto", dont use it` https://twitter.com/jbogard/status/1038041038496124928 It's definitely *not* meant to include JSON parsing logic.

Comment: You should probably *deserialize* the contents of the `LocationInfo` property and use a strongly typed object for that property. You don't gain anything by postponing that step until you have to map the result to a new object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ResolveUsing` method when you need to execute some methods inside mapping. For your case it will be:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Country, opts => opts.ResolveUsing(src => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LocationInfo>(src.LocationInfo).Country_Name);
```